# Understanding the definition of tangent vector

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I am struggling to understand the definition of tangent vector.

$\textbf{Definition.}$ Let $\bar{x}\in Q \subseteq R^n$. A vector $v\in R^n$ is tangent to $Q$ at $\bar{x}\in Q$ if there exists sequences $\{x_k\}\subseteq Q$ and $\{t_k\} \subset R_+$ such that
$$x_k\rightarrow \bar{x},\ t_k\downarrow 0,\ \frac{1}{t_k}(x_k-\bar{x})\rightarrow v.$$

$\textbf{Question.}$ This is the first time I've seen such a definition for a "tangent" vector, as I always thought that a tangent vector means a vector that touches a curve at exactly one point. But that aside, what really confuses me about this definition is that it seems to me that any vector $v$ can be tangent since as long as $$x_k\rightarrow \bar{x},\ t_k\downarrow 0,$$ 
we have
$$x_k\rightarrow \bar{x},\ t_kv\downarrow 0$$
and so
$$x_k \rightarrow \bar{x} + t_kv.$$

$\textbf{Edit.}$ Does the definition imply that $v$ is a tangent vector if $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $\bar{x}+\epsilon v \in Q$?

Comment: What precisely is meant by the notation $t_k\downarrow 0$?

Comment: Convergence to 0 from above then?

Comment: @ChristianSykes yes, convergence from above/from the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is almost perfectly correct, but at the last step, you've constructed a sequence $x_k$ that converges to $x$ as required, adn whose differences from $x$ all pooint in the right direction, etc.

But you've missed the important requirement on the $x_i$s, namely, that each $x_i$ **be an element of $Q$.**

Consider the case where $Q$ is the x-axis of the plane, and $v$ is the vertical vector $(0, 1)$, $t_k = 1/k$, and work through the details of what you've said to see why you have NOT proved that $v$ is tangent to $Q$.